# PHP - Specific scenario for storing login information

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication, storage

I'm making a PHP app to allow our customers to retrieve information from our database, using pre-defined functions. Perhaps PHP isn't the best choice for this, but the same page is also used as a backend for a flash app, and we don't have the time to rewrite it in another language (still, if we did have that time, I'm open to suggestions).

They will access the page via a URL, something like:

`http://myurl.com/test.php?function=getUser&username=John`

This will call the function `getUser($username)` and pass the value `John` as the `$username` parameter. **Here's the twist:** this page will be called from an application that the customer creates, not from a browser.

They are allowed to get info about some users, but not others. To enforce this, I require them to provide login information. I'm not sure how I can keep that user logged in so that they don't have to pass their login information every time they call a function, which can be multiple times per second.

I don't think I can use sessions or cookies, since they are not calling the page from a browser. So how can I keep that user logged in?

Comment: To start (*if you haven't*) you should read about RESTful web services (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#RESTful_web_services) and RPC (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) Those should definitely provide some insight as to how you can model your URI architecture among other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into setting up something like a SOAP API on your end.  Then, you can provide them with a token that goes back and forth (and possibly changes) between each request they make.

Have a read over [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) and see if it gives you any inspiration at the very least.  As far as implementing it, your options are many.  Maybe consider using a framework?

Comment: I tried looking into SOAP before, but was having trouble grasping the concept. However, seeing as how it is widely accepted and it has now been suggested from more than one source, I will definitely look into it more. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget about something like JSON, which is way simpler and IMO better.  I wrote a blog post about that includes a short explanation of SOAP.  Check it out if you'd like: http://www.thewebshop.ca/blog/2011/08/symfony-1-4-component-caching-and-soap/

Answer (score 0):

You've hit the stateless wall :D .

You will either need to create a session aware browser client object with some library or some token exchange. But as long as you are using a separate session between calls you will need to hit the database again to authorize the user; token or not.

Comment: At least I feel more confident that it wasn't dumb of me to run into this problem :-). Thanks for the additional insight.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: *You can't*, since HTTP is stateless.

But: You can use the same principle as cookies do, which is "send some authentification info along with the request without transmitting the secret". Have a look into **OAuth** and if it fits into your scenario. You can even use ready-made libraries for PHP.